# UNetbootin Not Working

Tags: software-installation

So I installed UNetbootin using "sudo apt-get install UNetbootin" and tried to start it from the programs menu, and it loaded, but the application's screen was grey and nothing happened. I even tried waiting ~10 minutes but nothing happened. Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/unetbootin/+bug/1620628.

The fix is to update from ppa:gezakovacs/ppa.

It appears this might not always work for 18.04, in which case the fix is to run it like this:
`sudo QT_X11_NO_MITSHM=1 unetbootin`